# SELECT all Tables with specific prefix except one

Tags: sql, sql-server

im trying to select (or delete) rows from many tables except one specific one.

Example:

One_Table_A

One_Table_A1

One_Table_A2

One_Table_A3

One_Table_B

One_Table_B1

One_Table_B2

Now I want to select  (or delete) rows from all tables except for "One_Table_B".

I got as far as:

```
SELECT 'DELET FROM '+TABLE_NAME +' WHERE ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'One_Table_';
```

Now i need some kind of exception for "One_Table_B"

Any idea?

Comment: AND  TABLE_NAME <> 'One_Table_B'

Comment: It's `DELETE`, not `DELET` or `DELTE`. Also you don't `DELETE` a table, you `DELETE` a row; you `DROP` a table.

Comment: Side note:  An underscore represents a single character wild card in `LIKE` so a table called `OneSTableHorse` will be matched by  `One_Table_%`. If you want to avoid this wrap your underscore in square brackets, i.e. `LIKE 'One[_]Table[_]%'` or use an escape character, e.g. `LIKE 'One\_Table\_%` ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: @Larnu, ur totaly correct, my bad

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This smells like an attempt to manually partition a table and delete older partitions. All supported SQL Server versions offer table partitioning out of the box, even Express and LocalDB. Unlike what you try to do, moving partitions between tables or clearing them out can be very fast. You can use `TRUNCATE` with a specific partition. You can swap partitions between tables in milliseconds (it's only a metadata operation). Querying doesn't change and doesn't require a UNION of all tables

Comment: Im trying to clean up some tables which contain specific rows. Also, many tables who have specific names are old and not used any more. These tables need to be dropped as well. But i had one exception and didnt know the hint given by SeanR :)